# View repository activity across all repositories under an account at the same time?

Tags: github

Is there a way to [view repository traffic](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/viewing-a-summary-of-repository-activity) for all repositories on your account at the same time? (without creating your own custom dashboard using the Github API). It would be very convenient. I suspect a bash script might do this without too much effort (e.g. get all repo names, get the traffic/stars stats for each repo in the list). But I want to be sure something obvious doesn't already exist before writing anything myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not ware of any *native* dashboard that would aggregate multiple GitHub repositories into one convenient view.

You would therefore have to rely on third-party scripts, such as, for example, [`nchah/github-traffic-stats`](https://github.com/nchah/github-traffic-stats) (Python)

> Get statistics on web traffic to your GitHub repositories.

Since it is limited to the last two weeks, you might have to record those statitics over time (example: [`Microsoft/GitHubTelemetryParsor`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GitHubTelemetryParsor))

Comment: Very useful, it works, but is there a programatic way to run it for every repository at once? (note that `gts username repo1 repo2 repo3` doesn't seem to work (it returns just the stats for the first repo, `repo1`).

Comment: @stevec From the README, that would be `gts username ALL`.

Comment: oops I missed that. Thanks very much